# android sliding menu from bottom to top using fragment

Tags: android, slidingmenu

In Android I want to make sliding menu like   [THIS](https://blog.gli.ph/2012/11/27/slide-on-in-new-menu-and-improved-secure-picture-messaging/)  Now i want to make this sliding menu same it is but Menu Button must be at the bottom. and menu opens from bottom to top how can i Achieve this?

[I have tried this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/11/android-sliding-menu-animation.html)  And [This also](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.in/2012/07/sliding-panel-from-top-to-bottom.html) But i am not getting usefull output i want the same as first screen shot but menu at bottom and it expand up to certain height(menu must not cover full height)

i want it using fragment.

I have tried this [also](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

I want it like [THIS](http://blog.neteril.org/wp-content/uploads/framelayout/sliding-panel.gif)

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (menu, slide, top, bottom) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 4):

I have post the link as an answer: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

The library will help you to achieve what you need.

The 2.2 version of the Umano Android app features a sexy sliding up draggable panel for the currently playing article. This type of a panel is a common pattern also used in the Google Music app and the Rdio app. This is an open source implementation of this component that you are free to take advantage of in your apps. Umano Team Open Source.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppaneldemo.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```